# Appcelerator Android HTTPClient service login

Tags: android, redirect, httpclient, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm developing an app for ios and android. This app MUST log in against a CAS service. After the log in is success in the CAS service it redirects to another page where i call other views and services in that same domain.

With IOS, it works fine, i log in and i can use the same HTTPclient or a new one, that the calls to the other services in the same domain work fine.

With Android i send the Data to log in, but the header returns :

```
null:HTTP/1.0 302 Found\nConnection:Keep-Alive\nContent-Length:0\nLocation:https://url.url.com\nServer:BigIP\nX-Android-Received-Millis:1458215497618\nX-Android-Sent-Millis:1458215497577\n
```

I have tried to send it to that location instead. It returns a 200 code, but when i try to call the other services of the domain it sais "Access denied for user anonymous"

Has someone encountered something similar? Or can provide some help?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are calling an API via `http` that requires (so redirects to) `https`. It's a [known issue](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-11863) that on Android we don't handle redirects with scheme change well. It will be fixed in 5.4, but the PR is there so you could do a custom build of the SDK version you use, patched using this PR.

However, why not just call the correct URL directly? That should work?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The correct URL also had a redirect but by adding a new call to the location pointed by the HTTPClient we could make it work.